# How to use ec2-modify-instance-attribute command from Ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to modify an AWS instance from within ansible.

My playbook is designed to compile and install ixgbevf driver on a running AWS instance then shuts it down so that a ec2-modify-instance-attribute command can be run.

Everything up to the last part of the equation works.

My final role stanza looks like this:

```
- name: Turn on enhanced networking on on the AMI host
  local_action: ec2-modify-instance-attribute the_instance_id={{ my_instance_id }}  --sriov simple --region us-west-2
  with_items: ec2_info.instances
  ignore_errors: yes
```

When the role runs I get the following errror:

```
fatal: [10.11.31.48 -> 127.0.0.1] => module ec2-modify-instance-attribute not found in configured module paths
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Is there actually a way to use the ec2-modify-instance-attribute command from within Ansible?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this CLI workaround

```
local_action:
  module: >
    shell
      aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id "{{ ec2_id }}"
      --groups "{{ec2_security_group_ids}}" "{{newgroup.group_id}}"
   when: newgroup.group_id not in ec2_security_group_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following which worked:

```
- name: "Stop the AWS instance"
  local_action:
     module: ec2
     state: stopped
     aws_access_key: "{{ aws.ec2.access_key_id }}"
     aws_secret_key: "{{ aws.ec2.secret_access_key }}"
     instance_ids: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
     region: "{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
     wait: True
```